# Time and Date not showing and the options are faded

Tags: 13.10, settings, time, date

I like being able to see the date and time in the upper-right hand portion of my screen. Recently, my time and date have disappeared. I tried adjusting Time and Date through System Settings. I noticed that the 'clock' tab is faded and unadjustable. How can I fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed this a few days ago too (possibly during a system upgrade). A restart fixed the issue. I guess the applet just crashed. Does the issue reappear after a restart?

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. Restarting the computer fixed the issue, I think it's going away after my computer is idling for too long. I tried the _sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime_ and my message mentioned that it was already installed to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, the package was not missing, but crashed somewhen and was maybe frozen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the date/time applet.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

And then get Unity to reload it.

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the package indicator-datetime

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the date-time indicator. Use:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```